# Where clause for JSON field on array of objects

Tags: mysql, json

Working with MySQL 5.7.19, I swear an hour ago this worked, but now im getting nothing returned from my query

```
CREATE TABLE FlattenedData.blog_posts
(
  post_id CHAR(13) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
  post_data JSON,
  date_published DATETIME NOT NULL, # for primary indexing
  date_added DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  date_updated DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  post_categories VARCHAR(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (post_data->>"$.categories[*].slug"),
  post_tags VARCHAR(512) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (post_data->>"$.tags[*].slug"),
  KEY idx_date_published (date_published),
  INDEX idx_categories (post_categories),
  INDEX idx_tags (post_tags),
  INDEX idx_categories_tags (post_categories, post_tags)
);
```

as a note: a post can have multiple categories, just like tags

Here's my query

```
select
  *
from blog_posts
WHERE
  post_data->>"$.categories[*].slug" = "site-news"
```

Like I said, I swear this was working earlier, but now I get nothing back.

Here's the explain:

[image]

Even if I delete the indexes and generated columns and just use plain json field, I still suddenly get nothing.  The only thing I can use that gets results, is `JSON_SEARCH`, but there's thousands of records and these are rather large json blobs, and it's possible the searched text can show up in the body

btw, a category field looks like this

`[{slug: "site-news", title: "Site News"}, {slug: "personal", title: "Personal"}]`

tags follow exactly the same structure

---

**EDIT**

I just tried with `post_data->>"$.categories[0].slug" = "site-news"` and that brought in records. But I need the where clause to take into consideration all elements of the array as I cannot guarantee the array element slot this category is going to be in.

As MySQL's docs state: `[*] represents the values of all cells in the array.` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-path-syntax.html

A core problem of using

```
select
  *
from blog_posts
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(post_data->"$.categories[*].slug", json_quote("site-news"))
```

is that it completely avoids using my indexes, which is going to be key here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path expression with wildcard returns an array of values, as an array in JSON notation.

```
SELECT post_data->>'$[*].slug' FROM blog_posts;
+---------------------------+
| post_data->>'$[*].slug'   |
+---------------------------+
| ["site-news", "personal"] |
+---------------------------+
```

That's clearly not equal to the scalar string 'site-news'.

So you an use JSON_SEARCH() on the JSON array to find a specific string:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(post_data->>'$[*].slug', 'one', 'site-news') IS NOT NULL;
```

I tested that with MySQL 8.0.3-rc. I loaded this data:

```
INSERT INTO blog_posts (post_id, date_published, post_data)
VALUES('blah blah', now(), '[{"slug": "site-news", "title": "Site News"}, {"slug": "personal", "title": "Personal"}]');
```

I know this isn't the format of your post_data, but it still demonstrates that using a wildcard path on JSON returns an array.

Comment: Hmm, I completely hear what you're saying, and I was afraid of that. sadly, usage of these functions seems to ignore my indexes according to explain.  But, I think if I were to use `JSON_CONTAINS(post_categories, json_quote("site-news"))` (using the generated column) then that can be probably as efficient as possible, while still kinda-maybe-sorta-ish making use of the index in the way of an auto chunked out segregated json array. At least it'd prevent the need to get mysql to do partial searching work on a huge json document for thousands of records at a time, even with a provided path..

Comment: Though, as I run my query, whether im targeting the `post_categories` generated field, or the `post_data->"$.categories[*].slug` path, seems to make no difference at all in the time taken. In my database anyways, both are taking an average of 19ms to return back a list of 10 records, sorted by an indexed date column `desc`, filtering on a specific single category. I think this should be fine