# Convert MySQL LONGTEXT column to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, collation

I have an existing table that holds valid JSON data but is stored as LONGTEXT (character set utf8mb4 with collation utf8mb4_bin). Doing JSON queries on this is highly inefficient and I want to change the data type of this column to JSON.

When I do so in HeidiSQL I get an: 'COLLATION 'utf8mb4_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'. **I can fix this by resetting the collation to empty.**

I mention this because I thought the character set for a JSON column is utf8mb4 and it's default collation is utf8mb4_bin. In the JSON are some GUIDs and when I try to query them, it appears that I have to use LIKE. If I use the 'normal' = I get no results.

Works: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Data->>"$.Shop[*].ContactPerson.UserId" LIKE "%b1b9ad95-1098-4e6c-a697-50c2a47dc301%";`

Doesn't work: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Data->>"$.Shop[*].ContactPerson.UserId" = "b1b9ad95-1098-4e6c-a697-50c2a47dc301";`

Is that a problem with my syntax or is it related to collation (I'd say no, but it's the only discrepancy I find). *BTW: Leaving out the % in the LIKE also produces no results.*

Create/insert:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp ( `Data` LONGTEXT COLLATE UTF8MB4_BIN );
INSERT INTO Temp( `Data` ) VALUES ("{\"Shop\":[{\"ContactPerson\": {\"UserId\":\"b1b9ad95-1098-4e6c-a697-50c2a47dc301\"}},{\"ContactPerson\": {\"UserId\":\"B27DA5A7-D678-4513-8A44-BD76CC4651CC\"}}]}");
INSERT INTO Temp( `Data` ) VALUES ("{\"Shop\":[{\"ContactPerson\": {\"UserId\":\"82899A81-2024-4F68-917A-710764296A21\"}},{\"ContactPerson\": {\"UserId\":\"AE59DCA7-32AF-4131-93C7-A1BB698DF8E0\"}}]}");
INSERT INTO Temp( `Data` ) VALUES ("{\"Shop\":[{\"ContactPerson\": {\"UserId\":\"4154477B-1B70-4F25-9E4B-2CFBBF4F678F\"}},{\"ContactPerson\": {\"UserId\":\"B27DA5A7-D678-4513-8A44-BD76CC4651CC\"}}]}");
```

Trying the update: `` ALTER TABLE `Temp` MODIFY `Data` JSON; ``

***And now it works... (of course) :(***

So apparently when using the table-editor in HeidiSQL it fails (I've retried this). Using a SQL statement actually does what I want.

*That still leaves me with having to use the LIKE as opposed to = in my query.*

Thank you to @Rick James for the "aha moment": [Where clause for JSON field on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437266/where-clause-for-json-field-on-array-of-objects)

So in my case:

```
SELECT * FROM `Temp` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(`Data`, 'one', 'b1b9ad95-1098-4e6c-a697-50c2a47dc301', NULL, '$.Shop[*].ContactPerson.UserId') IS NOT NULL;
```

Update:
Issue was reported and will be fixed in next build (https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/1652)

Comment: *I thought the character set for a JSON column is utf8mb4 and it's default collation is utf8mb4_bin.* - this is true, and this is described in the [Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) explicitly.

Comment: Provide a sample which reproduces this issue (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with sample data, 3-5 rows, no excess columns, and ALTER TABLE which changes the datatype).

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT Data->>"$.Shop[*].ContactPerson.UserId" FROM ...` or `SELECT LENGTH(Data->>"$.Shop[*].ContactPerson.UserId") FROM ...` ?

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid now... I'm getting a JSON array because Shop[*].
`["b1b9ad95-1098-4e6c-a697-50c2a47dc301", "B27DA5A7-D678-4513-8A44-BD76CC4651CC"]`. So yes it contains the element, but also others. Which also explains the need for % on both side of the LIKE.

Comment: May I suggest you [point this problem out](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues) to Ansgar Backer, HeidiSQL's author?